# I want to make a translation app in swift. Can anyone help me?

Tags: ios, swift, translation

I'm developing an app for translating word to word from English to my local dialect. Since there are no existing translation services for my dialect, I have to create a dictionary of words for each English word and return the local word for it. Here is sample code I found. But this code is for ecoding character by charcter instead of word by word translation. Can someone help me with a code to translate each word?

> for eg:  "apple = aaple"

Here is the sample code.

```
var code = [
    "a" : "b",
    "b" : "c",
    "c" : "d",
    "d" : "e",
    "e" : "f",
    "f" : "g",
    "g" : "h",
    "h" : "i",
    "i" : "j",
    "j" : "k",
    "k" : "l",
    "l" : "m",
    "m" : "n",
    "n" : "o",
    "o" : "p",
    "p" : "q",
    "q" : "r",
    "r" : "s",
    "s" : "t",
    "t" : "u",
    "u" : "v",
    "v" : "w",
    "w" : "x",
    "x" : "y",
    "y" : "z",
    "z" : "a"
]

var message = "hello world"
var encodedMessage = ""

for char in message.characters {
    var character = "\(char)"

    if let encodedChar = code[character] {
        // letter
        encodedMessage += encodedChar
    } else {
        // space
        encodedMessage += character
    }
}

print(encodedMessage)
```

Comment: It looks like you have a long ways to go. Put more work into this then come back with specific questions.

Comment: @Developer I would appreciate if you could point me towards a tutorial or a sample project.

Comment: Did you do any preliminary research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are creating a code dictionary with characters. You need to modify this and provide word and it's translation.

For e.g.

```
var code = [
    "hello" : "halo",
    "world" : "earth",
    "apple" : "aapl"
    //Add more translations here
]
```

Now, you need to split the input string into individual words. You can do this using `split`

**Complete code**

```
var code = [
    "hello" : "halo",
    "world" : "earth",
    "apple" : "aapl"
    //Add more translations here
]

let message = "hello world"

var encodedMessage = ""

//Split message String into words seperated by space(" ")
let array = message.characters.split(" ")

for singleWord in array {

    let word = String(singleWord)
    if let encodedWord = code[word] {
        // word
        encodedMessage += encodedWord
    } else {
        // word not found in the map
        encodedMessage += word
    }
    // seperate each word with a space
    encodedMessage += " "
}
```

Comment: if the grammar is consistent about english and the OPs dialect. this is valid.

Comment: Do not put the dictionary in code. A dictionary large enough for an entire language will be far too big to hard code in the app. Put the data in a database so it can be queried as needed.

Comment: This code is working perfectly. Thanx for the help and @Daij-Djan good suggestion. Appreciate it. And what would you suggest be the best database option. iCloud vs plist ?

Comment: @Dr.Ax Neither iCloud or plist is a database. You should use sqlite. You can create a full database of the translations and package the database with your app.